# Reshaping loosely structured JSON (field names stored in array)

Tags: jq

I have a unique problem I have been struggling to get my head wrapped around.  I have a bit of JSON from an API.  The field names are actually stored in **.headerData.methodNames** and most of the values are stored in **.lightValueObjects[].data**.

```json
{
  "headerData": {
    "objectTypeName": "device",
    "methodNames": [
      "name",
      "accessIp",
      "deviceType",
      "version",
      "discoverTime",
      "discoverMethod",
      "status",
      "department",
      "description",
      "perfMonStatus",
      "eventLogStatus",
      "maintenance",
      "location",
      "agentStatus",
      "policyName",
      "policyId",
      "agentType",
      "templateIds",
      "agentId",
      "decommission",
      "accountId",
      "instanceId",
      "agentVersion",
      "parserName"
    ]
  },
  "lightValueObjects": [
    {
      "objectId": 17657,
      "custId": 1,
      "parentId": null,
      "collectorId": null,
      "data": [
        "super",
        "192.168.128.222",
        "leader",
        null,
        1637092568000,
        "LOG",
        1,
        "Super",
        null,
        "",
        "Normal",
        "",
        null,
        "",
        "",
        "",
        null,
        "",
        null,
        false,
        "",
        "",
        null,
        ""
      ],
      "extData": null,
      "naturalId": "lead%2dsuper",
      "aoSys": false
    },
    {
      "objectId": 883252,
      "custId": 1,
      "parentId": null,
      "collectorId": null,
      "data": [
        "fw01",
        "192.168.128.1",
        "fw",
        "ANY",
        1637098725000,
        "LOG",
        1,
        "Super",
        null,
        "",
        "Normal",
        "",
        null,
        "",
        "",
        "",
        null,
        "",
        null,
        false,
        "",
        "",
        null,
        ""
      ],
      "extData": null,
      "naturalId": "fw01",
      "aoSys": false
    }
  ],
  "errCode": 0,
  "errObj": null,
  "dataType": "Device",
  "totalCount": 0
}
```

The following code produces better output, but it's not quite perfect.

```
.headerData.methodNames as $header | [.lightValueObjects[].data] | map(
      . as $o |
      reduce .[] as $item({}; ($o | index($item)) as $index |
      .[$header[$index]] = (if $item == "" then null else $item end))
      )
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "super",
    "accessIp": "192.168.128.222",
    "deviceType": "leader",
    "version": null,
    "discoverTime": 1637092568000,
    "discoverMethod": "LOG",
    "status": 1,
    "department": "Super",
    "perfMonStatus": null,
    "eventLogStatus": "Normal",
    "decommission": false
  },
  {
    "name": "fw01",
    "accessIp": "192.168.128.1",
    "deviceType": "fw",
    "version": "ANY",
    "discoverTime": 1637098725000,
    "discoverMethod": "LOG",
    "status": 1,
    "department": "Super",
    "description": null,
    "perfMonStatus": null,
    "eventLogStatus": "Normal",
    "decommission": false
  }
]
```

**Current Problems**

1. There should be 24 fields returned per device, but only 11 are being shown.
2. I have not been able to figure out how to merge the named values in .lightValueObjects to the final output.

Here is an example of what I am trying to make the output show, (To keep things simple, I am only showing 1 device)

```json
[
  {
    "name": "super",
    "accessIp": "192.168.128.222",
    "deviceType": "leader",
    "version": null,
    "discoverTime": 1637092568000,
    "discoverMethod": "LOG",
    "status": 1,
    "department": "Super",
    "description": null,
    "perfMonStatus": null,
    "eventLogStatus": "Normal",
    "maintenance": null,
    "location": null,
    "agentStatus": null,
    "policyName": null,
    "agentType": null,
    "templateIds": null,
    "agentId": null,
    "decommission": false,
    "accountId": null,
    "instanceId": null,
    "agentVersion": null,
    "parserName": null,
    "objectId": 17657,
    "custId": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "collectorId": null,
    "extData": null,
    "naturalId": "lead%2dsuper",
    "aoSys": false
  }
]
```

Any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got all your alignments right, but give this a try:

```
.headerData.methodNames as $header
| .lightValueObjects | map(
  ( [$header, .data]
    | transpose
    | map({(first): last})
    | add
  ) + del(.data)
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "super",
    "accessIp": "192.168.128.222",
    "deviceType": "leader",
    "version": null,
    "discoverTime": 1637092568000,
    "discoverMethod": "LOG",
    "status": 1,
    "department": "Super",
    "description": null,
    "perfMonStatus": "",
    "eventLogStatus": "Normal",
    "maintenance": "",
    "location": null,
    "agentStatus": "",
    "policyName": "",
    "policyId": "",
    "agentType": null,
    "templateIds": "",
    "agentId": null,
    "decommission": false,
    "accountId": "",
    "instanceId": "",
    "agentVersion": null,
    "parserName": "",
    "objectId": 17657,
    "custId": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "collectorId": null,
    "extData": null,
    "naturalId": "lead%2dsuper",
    "aoSys": false
  },
  {
    "name": "fw01",
    "accessIp": "192.168.128.1",
    "deviceType": "fw",
    "version": "ANY",
    "discoverTime": 1637098725000,
    "discoverMethod": "LOG",
    "status": 1,
    "department": "Super",
    "description": null,
    "perfMonStatus": "",
    "eventLogStatus": "Normal",
    "maintenance": "",
    "location": null,
    "agentStatus": "",
    "policyName": "",
    "policyId": "",
    "agentType": null,
    "templateIds": "",
    "agentId": null,
    "decommission": false,
    "accountId": "",
    "instanceId": "",
    "agentVersion": null,
    "parserName": "",
    "objectId": 883252,
    "custId": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "collectorId": null,
    "extData": null,
    "naturalId": "fw01",
    "aoSys": false
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xtZMyxqxGj)

Edit: If you want to replace empty strings `""` with `null`, as you did in your approach, replace `last` from my solution with either `(last | select(. != "") // null)` or, more explicitly, with  `(last | if . == "" then null else . end)`.

Comment: This works like a champ! And is much cleaner than mine!

One thing to note, I tried the (select(last != "") // null) but it replaced the "" with an array.

I ended up using (if last == "" then null else last end)

Thank you so much!

Comment: My bad, should have been `(last | select(. != "") // null)`. But going with an `if-then-else-end` is fine, too.